# Websocket : Is wss faster than ws?

Tags: websocket

I am developing a small game where latency matters and I have been reading this article https://samrueby.com/2015/01/26/why-is-https-faster-than-http/ and it claims that Https is faster than Http. I know that in HTTP connection is opened to transfer a single file/text/image and closes whereas in websocket connection stays open once handshake is done. I wanna know if data transfer speed can have some boost with secure connection in case of websocket.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets isn't HTTP, even though the handshake is compatible. It doesn't rely on SPDY (by default, I get into this later), nor can it use HTTP2, so anything mentioned by the article doesn't apply here.

However, there's a flag for chrome, which enables websockets over SPDY (`--enable-websocket-over-spdy`), but since Chrome is going to remove SPDY support in a future release and most browsers don't have this, I wouldn't count on it.

Use WSS, when you need security, not for speed